# raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)

Tags: python

I am getting the following error while trying to parse a link using beautiful soup,looks like the authentication is failing....how to authenticate the link?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import argparse
import urllib
import urllib2
import getpass
import re

def update (searchurl):
    page = urllib2.urlopen(searchurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    #print(soup.textarea.string)
    print(soup.get_text())

def main ():
    #For logging
    print "test"
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is the update.py script created by test')
    parser.add_argument('-u','--url',action='store',dest='url',default=None,help='<Required> url link',required=True)
    results = parser.parse_args()# collect cmd line args
    url = results.url
    #print url
    update(url)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Following is the error while trying to open the link

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "announce_update2.py", line 24, in <module>
        main()
      File "announce_update2.py", line 22, in main
        update(url)
      File "announce_update2.py", line 9, in update
        page = urllib2.urlopen(searchurl)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
        return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 406, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 438, in error
        result = self._call_chain(*args)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 625, in http_error_302
        return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 406, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 444, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
```

Comment: any luck!? I'm having that same issue using AppEngine!

Comment: @Bach - problem is you should authenticate the URL ,before trying to login

Comment: Mine is different then because I'm using AppEngine on localhost, and there is no Authentication. I found the solution to my problem. I was running Charles debugger in the background while testing it must have done something to the request. Closing Charles then restarting AppEngine seems to fix it. Tried this many times and seems consistent issue. Had issues authenticating to Facebook as well when Charles debugger is running. hope that helps someone with similar issue.